# How to detect whether my android device supports otg cable in android

Tags: android, usb-drive, usb-otg

I want to detect whether my android smart phone supports USB On-The-Go .  I have searched a lot in the internet but could not find any way to do that !

I have found that there is an application "USB OTG Checker" . Here is some screenshot of that app .

[image]

How can I check whether an USB is plugged in smartphone ?

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Answer (score 2):

Actually USB Host actually similar with OTG,since we can check the USB Host feature programically, here are my solution,hope this help you.

```
    /**
 * Check the device whether has USB-HOST feature.
 */
public static boolean hasUsbHostFeature(Context context) {
    return context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_USB_HOST);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your **answer** is here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34691806/3818437

add a `<uses-feature>` element to your `manifest`, indicating that you are interested in the `android.hardware.usb.host` feature.

**OR** use `PackageManager, hasSystemFeature(), and FEATURE_USB_HOST`. `FEATURE_USB_HOST` is defined as the same string as you would be using in `<uses-feature>`(android.hardware.usb.host).