# How to check whether Android device supports OTG features programatically

Tags: android, usb-otg

I want to check whether a device supports OTG features programatically . I have tried a lot about this in Internet but could not find any thing .

How can I do that ?

Comment: What 'lot' have you tried?

Answer (score 6):

thnx to @CommonsWare: [How to detect if Android has full USB support or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934248/how-to-detect-if-android-has-full-usb-support-or-not/23934631#23934631)

The official way to determine if the device has USB host capability is to use the associated system feature.

Ideally, add a `<uses-feature>` element to your manifest, indicating that you are interested in the `android.hardware.usb.host` feature.

**OR** use `PackageManager.hasSystemFeature(), and FEATURE_USB_HOST`.

`FEATURE_USB_HOST` is defined as the same string as you would be using in `<uses-feature> (android.hardware.usb.host)`.

**in code words:**

```
context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_USB_HOST);
```

Comment: Using above code, always i am getting "True" from device which is not support otg. @mhdjazmati

Comment: I am using this code and its working , maybe a bug on the device that you use ...

Comment: I am trying with more than 25 device which is not support otg.But always we getting "True".

Comment: For most of the devices chekced, it returns true. Even when there is no USB host support

Comment: this was a bug but after API19 it got fixed

Comment: I am getting "True" even if the it's API 21 . Any suggestions?